# Problem exporting a mixture of PAL and ProRes 422 in FCP

Tags: final-cut-pro, codec, prores

I have a FCP sequence made of a mixture of ProRes 422 and PAL clips. As soon as I export it using "QuickTime Movie" (Apple ProRes 422 PAL 48KHz option), the quality of the ProRes clips is superb, but the PAL section look horrible (they look fine in the timeline). The same happens for the transitions effects, even if the transitions are between two ProRes clips. During the transitions, the quality of the exported movie drops dramatically.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried sending it to compressor and then using ProRes? The built in exporting functions in FCP7 are not the best

Comment: I'll bet it is a problem related to interlacing and frame rate. What frame rate is everything at (timeline, 422 clips, and PAL clips)?

Comment: @Colum: tried with send to compressor. Same result.

Comment: @Dave: Everything is at 25 fps.

Comment: Maybe link us to a sample clip?

Comment: Apparently, FCP recognizes the current size of some of the clips to be 477x357, even if none of them has that dimension. When exported to 720x576, these clips degrade. Apparently, I'm not the only one struggling with this issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2379503?start=0&tstart=0 Where does this 477x357 come from???

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered this problem, so unfortunately I can't give you advice on how to fix it. However, next time, I would suggest that you convert all your footage to the same format before you begin editing. Prores 422 is a great editing codec.

Go to [this](http://www.squared5.com/) website and download MPEG Streamclip. It's a free program that converts your footage to different codecs. Much better than Compressor IMO.

I usually convert all my footage to Apple Prores 422 (HQ) and then, upon completion, export a Quicktime H.264.

Answer (score 0):

The transitions going horrible tell us the problem is the sequence settings(when it renders, go ugly). Check codec and quality settings, you have a lot of work in sequence settings tab. For the "scale" 477x357 problem, I suggest to turn **off** in FCP preferences to (stupidly)auto-adjust size for sequences and manual reinsert clip (and manual make any scale/aspect ratio adjustments).
You can try export in *None* compression to see if it is only a codec problem. And finally, you can export just a small part of your timeline to make your tests faster. Tell us what it works!